# Google oAuth 2.0 localhost resolution

Tags: authentication, oauth

How does google authentication server resolve localhost address in their callback?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An OAuth 2 authenticating party never contacts the relying party.

Instead, it sends a 302 redirect response to the browser, telling it to go back to the relying party (and passing the result code in the query string).
Your browser is perfectly capable of resolving localhost.